# marshmallow dataclasses can't be deserialized with an excluded field

Tags: python-3.x, marshmallow

I have a hierarchical definition of dataclasses for which I use marshmallow to serialize/deserialize them.

In certain dataclasses there are fields that should not be serialized which I can do using the `class Meta`, however, when then deserializing the the same object back it throws an exception.

Here's an example of the problem

```
import uuid
import dataclasses
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import Tuple, List, Any
from marshmallow import Schema, EXCLUDE
from marshmallow_dataclass import class_schema


@dataclass(init=False)
class Base:
    id: uuid.UUID = field(default=None)

    class Meta:
        ordered = True
        additional = ['id']


    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        fields = dataclasses.fields(self)
        names = set([f.name for f in fields])
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            if k in names:
                setattr(self, k, v)

        if self.id is None:
            self.id = uuid.uuid4()


@dataclass(init=False)
class User(Base):
    name: str
    _options: List[Any] = field(default_factory=list)

    class Meta:
        unknown = EXCLUDE
        exclude = ['_options']

    @property
    def options(self) -> list:
        return self._options


@dataclass(init=False)
class Person(Base):
    location: str
    _address: List[Any] = field(default_factory=list)

    class Meta:
        unknown = EXCLUDE
        exclude = ['_address']


user = User()
user.name = 'test_user'

person = Person()
person.location = 'earth'


user_schema = class_schema(User)()
person_schema = class_schema(Person)()

serialized_user = user_schema.dump(user)
serialized_person = person_schema.dump(person)

print(serialized_user)
print(serialized_person)

deserialized_user = user_schema.load(serialized_user)
print(deserialized_user)
```

How can the serialized object be deserialzed with the excluded fields?

Comment: Is working with `marshmallow` a requirement for the task?

Comment: In a sense yes, I'm using it to serialize application data/settings onto the filesystem

Comment: I'm not too familiar with marshmallow actually. In this case, does it have uses other than to load/dump a class instance?

Comment: Also, I noticed that User has an `_options` field that doesn't seem to be used. There's a similar named read-only property `options`, which seems to return a separate list.

Comment: My bad, the property should return the actual `_options`; marshmallows purpose is to serialize and deserialize python objects

Comment: Please edit your question to include which exception, and the sample dump

Comment: It appears to me based on the docs that the `exclude=` flag only has relevance during dump, so the fields are still being expected during the load. Im hesitant to place this as an answer since I havent run it myself, but I suspect you need to flag the fields as `dump_only` in addition to excluding them in the meta. This should trigger the fields to be treated as `unknown` during the read, and fall into the `unknown=EXCLUDE` handling.